# Getting all the datasources configured in applicationContext.xml file?

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring/hibernate. i have configured 5 datasources in applicationContext.xml file. All datasources are of com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource type but ids are different. how can i get all the configured datasources when i have application context. i am getting application context as below:

```
WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all beans of the given type as follows:

```
Map<String, DataSource> dataSources = context.getBeansOfType(DataSource.class);
```

Values in this `Map` are bean instances, keys are their ids.

Alternatively you can inject collection of beans of the given type into another bean as dependency, see [3.9.2 @Autowired and @Inject](http://3.9.2%20@Autowired%20and%20@Inject).